# Short dictanse from given latitude and longitude iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application i have array of latitude and longitude with 5-6 places i want to short distance from my current location and show it on my map view for example: i have 3 places location  A,B and C so i want to short them according to my current location if location C is near to my current location then first i want to show C location on MAP after that calculate location A and B with location C means which location is near to place C if B is near to place  C then show B location on map and at the last show location A

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 1):

To see the distance between two locations

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latA longitude:longA];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latB longitude:longB];
CLLocation *locC = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latC longitude:longC];
CLLocation *yourLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:yourLat longitude:yourLong];
```

then get the distances between the place and your location

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:yourLoc];
CLLocationDistance distance2 = [locB distanceFromLocation:yourLoc];
CLLocationDistance distance3 = [locC distanceFromLocation:yourLoc];
```

and finally compare the distances.